# Jquery randomly hide 2 number without repeating the previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i randomly chose any 2 numbers and hide it using jquery.
i know that i can just use the function twice and it will work 2 times.
but it will repeat the previous too. therefore sometime one of the element will not hide.

```
randomtip = function(){
            var length = $("li.ad1 a").length;
            var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
            $("li.ad1 a:nth-child(" + ran + " )").hide();
        };

        randomtip();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an if-else to check if the randomly selected element is hidden or not:

```
randomtip = function(){
        var length = $("li.ad1 a").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
        if($("li.ad1 a:eq(" + ran + ")").is(":hidden")) randomtip();
        else $("li.ad1 a:eq(" + ran + ")").hide();
    };

randomtip();
randomtip();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about,

```
var Aran;
randomtip = function(){
          var length =  $("li.ad1 a").length;
          var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
          if(Aran !=ran){
             $("li.ad1 a:nth-child(" + ran + " )").hide();
            Aran=ran;  
          }
          else{

             randomtip();
           }


        };
```

then call it twice!